# Поразрядная сортировка массива двоичных чисел(MSD)

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Суть задачи заключается в том, чтобы отсортировать массив, состоящий из двоичных чисел поразрядно от большего разряда к меньшему.

Сортировка происходит по следующему алгоритму: все числа упорядочиваются по цифре в самом старшем разряд, для этого массив просматривается от начала (ищется число с 1 в заданном разряде) и конца (ищется число с 0 в заданном разряде) к середине и выбирается пара чисел для обмена. В результате массив разбивается на две части с 0 и 1 в старших разрядах, к каждой из которых применяется сортировка  по цифре в разряде правее (при равенстве этих цифр сохранять упорядоченность по цифре в "предыдущем" разряде); и так далее до самого младшего разряда. В основе алгоритма поразрядной сортировки лежит абстрактная операция извлечения цифры в заданном разряде. Алгоритм рекурсивный. Код написан на C++.

Проблема в следующем: сортируются сначала числа с нулями, а затем с единицами, то есть при вводе массива [101010, 101, 1, 0, 111111] он отсортируется следующим образом : [0, 101, 101010, 1, 1111111]. Как исправить код, чтобы сортировался по возрастанию?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 25
using namespace std;

void array_input(int a[], int &max_len, int &size)
{
    cout << "Введите размер массива(2-25): ";
    while (1)
    {   
        cin >> size;
        if ((size < 1) || (size > N)) cout << "Размерность должна быть больше 1 и меньше 25! Введите заново: ";
        else break;
    }

    cout << "Заполните массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cin >> a[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//поиск максимальной длины элемента массива
    {
        int counter = 0, digit = a[i];

        while (digit != 0)
        {
            counter++;
            digit /= 10;
        }
        if (counter > max_len) max_len = counter;
    }
}

void sort(int a[], int count_radix, int size)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= (int(size/2)+size%2-1); i++)
    {
        if (count_radix <= 1)
        {
            if (a[i] % 10 == 1)
            {
                for (int j = size - 1; j >= int(size / 2) + size % 2; j--)
                {
                    if (a[j]%10 == 0)
                    {
                        int t = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = t;
                        break;
                    }
                }
             }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((a[i] % int(pow(10, count_radix))) / int(pow(10, count_radix - 1)) == 1)
            {
                for (int j = size - 1; j >= int(size / 2) + size % 2; j--)
                {
                    if ((a[j] % int(pow(10, count_radix))) / int(pow(10, count_radix - 1)) == 0)
                    {
                        int t = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = t;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) if ((a[i] % int(pow(10, count_radix))) / int(pow(10, count_radix - 1))) break;

            if (count_radix > 0)
            {
                sort(a, count_radix - 1, i + 1);
                sort(a, count_radix - 1, size - i);
            }
        }

    }

}

int main()
{
    int a[N], max_len = 0, size;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    array_input(a, max_len, size);
    sort(a, max_len, size);
    cout << max_len << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << a[i] << "\t";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добейте их слева нулями...

Comment: Это не помогает

Comment: Вы неверно поняли алгоритм поразрядной сортировки. Вы написали что-то пузырьковоподобное. Поразрядная: 

1 проход сначала пишем числа у которых n-й бит =0, а потом те у которых 1. 
2. проход. В первой группе сначала пишем числа у которых n-1-й бит =0, а потом те у которых 1. Также во второй и т.д. https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Непонятно. Если у вас сортировка двоичных чисел, то что у вас делают `(pow(10, count_radix)` - это же десятичные цифры? И второе - ваше *поразрядно от большего разряда к меньшему* - приведет к тому, что ничего хорошего (сортировки) у вас не будет. Поразрядная сортировка выполняется **от меньшего разряда к большему**.